# wavelink cant search for youtube playlist

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try to use wavelink to search for youtubeplaylist and I get error

**Mycode**

```
 @commands.command(aliases=['P', 'PLAY', 'Play','p'])
  async def play(self,ctx: commands.Context, *, search:wavelink.YouTubePlaylist):
    print(search)
```

**Error**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3.10\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 456, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await method(ctx, argument)
  File "C:\Python3.10\lib\site-packages\wavelink\tracks.py", line 218, in convert
    return results[0]
TypeError: 'YouTubePlaylist' object is not subscriptable
```

And I also try Partial search `partial = wavelink.PartialTrack(query=search, cls=wavelink.YouTubePlaylist)` and this error came up instead

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3.10\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Tunwi\Desktop\test db\cogs\testmusic.py", line 102, in play
    await vc.play(vc.queue[0]['song'])
  File "C:\Python3.10\lib\site-packages\wavelink\player.py", line 241, in play
    "track": source.id,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

or there are anyway to do it? pls tell me and also sorry for my bad English